# Do I have the Skyrim DLCs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-hearthfire, skyrim-dragonborn

I bought Skyrim a time ago, but only the main game. I do not see the DLCs to buy anymore. Do I have them?

I went to the link mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/6isynp/skyrim_dlcs_missing_from_steam_store/), but it doesn't show the DLCs.

Comment: If you play it through Steam on PC then it will show you in the game window after you select it if you have them installed or not. If you are on a console, idk how to check it.

Comment: I went to your link and one of the posts said they were hidden and gave a link to buy them on steam.

Answer (score 1):

The DLCs as well as the original base game have been hidden, but are still accessible. This happens with other games as well when a remastered version is released.

If you had previously owned Skyrim: Dragonborn through steam, you would have automatically received the Skyrim: Special Edition, which is the remastered, all encompassing version of the game, at no additional cost when it was released. Once that version was released, they hid the original from the store.

Thankfully, I still have the base game in my library and was able to pull up the direct link to the DLC purchase page as well as a free texture upgrade patch. You can find those [here](https://store.steampowered.com/dlc/72850/) and if you already own one of the DLC packages, it will say "already in library". The base game is located [here](https://store.steampowered.com/app/72850/The_Elder_Scrolls_V_Skyrim/).

Give it some thought thought: Special Edition runs $40 whereas the DLC packages for the original version cost $45 ($40 of that is between Dawnguard and Dragonborn).